# Unable to multiply 2 columns in a dataframe to get a 3rd column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with student loan. There are 2 columns -

1. Exposure at Default (in lakh Rs.) - Total Outstanding Loan Amount
2. Recovery (%) - Possibility of amount that can be recovered in case of default
   I am trying to create a third column - 'Amount Recovered' - but the code is throwing error.

Here is my code -

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('Inferential Statistics - Student Loan.csv')
df2.head()
df2['Recovery (%)'] = df2['Recovery (%)'].apply(lambda x:x[:-1])
I have stripped of the % from the **'Recovery (%)'** column and converted the column to float
df2['Recovery (%)'].apply(np.float64)
```

The below code is not working and throwing error -

```
    df2['Loss'] = df2['Exposure at Default (in lakh Rs.)'] * df2['Recovery (%)']
```

**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'**

The link to the file is here -
https://github.com/rbiswas28/Machine-Learning/blob/main/Inferential%20Statistics%20-%20Student%20Loan.csv

Comment: you need to assign `df2['Recovery (%)'].apply(np.float64)` back to `df2['Recovery (%)']` Like this `df2['Recovery (%)'] = df2['Recovery (%)'].apply(np.float64)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the conversion:

```py
df2['Recovery (%)'] = df2['Recovery (%)'].apply(np.float64)
```

Then the dtype will stick:

```
df2['Loss'] = df2['Exposure at Default (in lakh Rs.)'] * df2['Recovery (%)']

# 0       230.0000
# 1         1.2240
# 2         0.9944
# 3        31.6249
# 4        68.8448
#           ...   
# 9995    399.5601
# 9996    703.5054
# 9997    307.5720
# 9998    907.7173
# 9999      0.6765
# Name: Loss, Length: 10000, dtype: float64
```